# read xml file with tlv format

Tags: c, readfile

I read xml file with tlv format, xml file has 593 byte, i reading the below code. Fırst 512 byte is true, but  the remaining bytes is false. I read the remainder byte is 00.

```
int fd,ret;
unsigned char *filebuffer[6400];

fd = open("filename" , O_RDONLY);
printf("file open return value : %d \n", fd);
if (fd == -1)
{
    printf("Error in openning the file!\n");
    exit(0);
}
//read the file
int i = 0;
do {
    ret = read(fd,&filebuffer[i],512);
    printf("file read return value : %d \n", ret);
    if (ret == -1)
    {
        printf("Error in reading!\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    i += ret;
    printf("i = %d, ret = %d",i,ret);

} while (ret > 0);

int k;
char tmp[6400];
memcpy(tmp,filebuffer,i);
printf("file buffer\n");
for (k = 0; k < i; ++k) {
    printf("%02x",tmp[i]);
}

close(fd);}
```

I filling the filebuffer with i'm reading xml file. 
filebuffer example; filebuffer : 1F0583212 ..... (512 byte) 000000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition for `filebuffer` is incorrect. Change it to:

```
unsigned char filebuffer[6400];
```